# SQL check if next row doesn't exist

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have an MsSQL server and what I am doing is selecting rows from the table. Currently I have two rows so I was wondering how would I check if there are no other rows after second one without making another query?

For example

table users

```
id    name    pass

1     joe     123

2     bob     abc
```

How would I check if there is no row after 2 with just a query? I am willing to combining it with my current query, which just selects the data.

Comment: How do you know you only want to look at those two rows?

Comment: Are you trying to do pagination? Or are you just looking if a row has been added since your last query?

Comment: I am trying to paginate, but its more complicated than this, its using jquery ajax and no page refresh, so the number of arguments that can be sent is limited, anyways is there a command in sql to check if next row doesn't exist?

Comment: Aside: If you don't specify an explicit order, there is no concept of "next".

Comment: That would be true, if the query selected different records every time, which it doesn't. So I would say there is a concept of "next", even for unordered results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the number of rows in your query as another column:

```
SELECT id, name, pass, count(*) over () as rows
FROM users
```

Keep in mind that this is telling you the number of rows returned by the query, not the number of rows in the table. However, if you specify a "TOP n" in your select, the rows column will give you the number of rows that would have been returned if you didn't have "Top n"

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to paginate the trick is to query one more record than you actually need for the current page. By counting the result (`mysql_num_rows`) and comparing that to your page size, you can then decide if there is a 'next page'.

If you were using mysql you could also use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS()` in your query, which calculates the number of rows that would be returned without the LIMIT clause. Maybe there is an equivalent for that in MsSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are inserting manually the first 2 rows of your table.

According to that, my idea is to just do a select where the id is more than 2 like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 2;
```

I also assume that you are using PHP so `mysql_num_rows` will return you `0` if no data is found, otherwise it will return you the number of rows from your query and now you know that you need to do a `while` or some loop to retrieve the data after id number 2.